# MSSQL Spatial vector features not showing up in QGIS 2.18 up

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I'm importing a MSSQL 2008 Spatial layer in QGIS. In version 2.14 it works OK, I can see the vector features and interact with the associated attribute tables. But in versions 2.18 and 2.99, though the connection is OK (I can see the attribute tables), the features are not showing up in the map canvas. I can even modify the data in the tables but I can't graphically select the features for editing.

I'm using a Windows 10 PC. The 3 versions of QGIS are runnig in the same machine, at the same time, with the same configuration. I've tried with the standalone installer and with the OSGEO4W installer (32 bit).

¿Anything changed from version 2.14 to newer versions that I can't get the features drawn on the map?

*ADDED 2017-10-23*

In QGIS 2.18.13, in the Layer Properties dialog for the **CAMPOS_geo** layer, under Metadata, there's a Properties section with this data:

```
General
    Storage type of this layer
    MSSQL spatial database

    Description of this provider
    MSSQL spatial data provider

    Source for this layer
    dbname='GIS' host=SERVER2 user='sa' srid=4326 type=Point table="dbo"."CAMPOS_geo" (CASCO_point) sql=

    Geometry type of the features in this layer
    Point (WKB type: "Point")

    The number of features in this layer
    611

    Capabilities of this layer
    Add Features, Delete Features, Change Attribute Values, Add Attributes, Delete Attributes, Create Spatial Index, Create Attribute Indexes, Fast Access to Features at ID, Change Geometries

Extents
    In layer spatial reference system units
    xMin,yMin -65.4273,-31.905 : xMax,yMax 0,0

    Layer Spatial Reference System
    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

And in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct18b.png) is the configuration of the **CAMPOS_geo** table in SQL Server.

[image: QGIS 2.14.19]
QGIS 2.14.19: Vector Features and associated data shown OK.

[image: QGIS 2.18.13]
QGIS 2.18.13: Data shown but Vector Features not shown.

[image: QGIS 2.99.0]
QGIS 2.99.0: Data shown but Vector Features not shown.

[image: MSSQL Spatial table]
 MSSQL Spatial table setup

Comment: 2.99 is not finished yet, so I'm guessing they haven't gotten to that yet... you should just use version 2.18

Comment: Try to recalculate geographic metadata under the layer properties. On 2.18 screenshot there are no  known coordinates and scale (look the botom bar : 0;0 )

Comment: How is the geometry stored? WKT or Binary?

Comment: ¿How do I recalculate metadata? I couldn´t find it under Layer Properties.